# ¿Cómo renderizo o itero los valores obtenidos desde una base de datos a un select usando Alpine.js en Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, alpinejs

Cómo renderizar los datos obtenidos por medio de una petición get a un select usando Alpine.js

Este es mi layout.html

```
{% load bootstrap5 %}
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        {% bootstrap_css %}
        {% bootstrap_javascript %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

        <!-- Agrega el script de Alpine.js -->
        <script src="{% static 'js/alpinejs@3.13.2.min.js' %}" defer></script>

        <!-- Agrega el script de Axios -->
        <script src="{% static 'js/axios.min.js' %}"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'sweetalert2/dark-theme.css' %}">
        <script src="{% static 'sweetalert2/sweetalert2.min.js' %}"></script>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body x-data="{ inputConcepto: null, inputSignificado: null, selectBimestre: null, selectMateria: null, selectUnidad: null,
                    urlRelativeGuardar: '{% url 'guardar' %}', responseData: null,
                    urlRelativeGetMaterias: '{% url 'mostrar_materias' %}', listMaterias: [],
                    urlRelativeGetUnidades: '{% url 'mostrar_unidades' %}', listUnidades: [],
                    data: {id: null, concepto: null, significado: null, bimestre: null, unidadU: null, materiaU: null} }">

        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block js %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Este es mi index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="mt-4 text-center fw-bold fst-italic">{{ h1 }}</h1>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <button style="margin: 0 auto; display: block" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalFormConcepto">Agregar nuevo concepto</button>
        {% include 'modals/form.html' %}
        {% include 'table.html' %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/get_materias.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/get_unidades.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/create_object.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/update_object.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

este es mi modal form.html

```
{% load static %}

<!-- Modal para agregar nuevo Concepto -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFormConcepto" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content bg-dark text-light">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">{{ h1_form }}</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close bg-danger close_modal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="inputConcepto" class="form-label fw-bold">Concepto:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="inputConcepto" x-model="inputConcepto" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <label for="significado" class="form-label fw-bold">Significado:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="significado" style="height: 250px" x-model="inputSignificado"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="col-md-5" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
                            <select x-model="selectBimestre" class="form-select text-center" aria-label="Large select example">
                                <option selected>{{ selected_bimestre }}</option>
                                {% for bimestre in bimestres %}
                                    <!-- Option para realizar la solicitud GET para obtener las Materias -->
                                    <option value="{{ bimestre }}" @click="getMaterias(urlRelativeGetMaterias, selectBimestre)">{{ bimestre }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="selectMateria" class="form-label fw-bold">Materia:</label>
                        <!-- Select para mostrar las materias obtenidas -->
                        <select id="selectMateria" x-model="selectMateria" class="form-select">
                            <option selected>{{ selected }}</option>
                            <template x-for="showMaterias in listMaterias">
                                <!-- Option para realizar la solicitud GET para obtener las Unidades -->
                                <option x-text="`${showMaterias.materia}.`" :value="showMaterias.id" @click="getUnidades"></option>
                            </template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="selectUnidad" class="form-label fw-bold">Unidad:</label>
                        <!-- Select para mostrar las unidades obtenidas -->
                        <select id="selectUnidad" x-model="selectUnidad" class="form-select">
                            <option selected>{{ selected }}</option>
                            <template x-for="showUnidades in listUnidades">
                                <option x-text="`${showUnidades.unidad}.`" :value="showUnidades.id"></option>
                            </template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="sendData">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esta es la vista del index en donde llega la petición get por medio de axios:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from materias.models import Materia, Unidad
from .models import Concepto


# Create your views here.
class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_index = {
            'title': 'Lista de Conceptos',
            'h1': 'Maestría en Educación y Docencia',
            'h1_form': 'Nuevo Concepto y Significado',
            'h5': 'Lista de conceptos con sus significados',
            'selected_bimestre': f"{'-' * 3} Bimestre: {'-' * 3}",
            'selected': '-' * 20,
            'bimestres': [f"{i}" for i in range(1, 10)],
            'conceptos': Concepto.objects.all()
        }
        return context_index


class MateriasView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        bimestre = request.GET.get('bimestre')

        if bimestre:
            materias = Materia.objects.filter(bimestre=bimestre)
            materias_data = [{'id': materia.id, 'materia': materia.materia} for materia in materias]
            return JsonResponse({'materias': materias_data})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Debes seleccionar un bimestre primero.'})


class UnidadesView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        materia = request.GET.get('materia')

        if materia:
            unidades = Unidad.objects.filter(materia=materia)
            unidades_data = [{'id': unidad.id, 'unidad': unidad.unidad} for unidad in unidades]
            return JsonResponse({'unidades': unidades_data})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Debes seleccionar una materia primero.'})
```

estas son las urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import Index, MateriasView, UnidadesView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Index.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('mostrar-materias', MateriasView.as_view(), name='mostrar_materias'),
    path('mostrar-unidades', UnidadesView.as_view(), name='mostrar_unidades'),
    path('api/', include('conceptos.api.urls')),
]
```

Esta es la función para obtener las materias que ya las obtengo pero no se renderizan en el select, get_materias.js:

```
const getMaterias = (url_get_materias, select_bimestre) => {
    let url = `${url_get_materias}?bimestre=${select_bimestre}`

    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        this.responseData = response.data
        this.listMaterias = response.data.materias || []

        console.log(this.listMaterias)

    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Error al obtener datos:', error)
    })
}
```

En esta parte es donde tengo las dificultades para renderizar es en los selects del form.html

```
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="col-md-5" style="margin: 0 auto; display: block;">
                            <select x-model="selectBimestre" class="form-select text-center" aria-label="Large select example">
                                <option selected>{{ selected_bimestre }}</option>
                                {% for bimestre in bimestres %}
                                    <!-- Option para realizar la solicitud GET para obtener las Materias -->
                                    <option value="{{ bimestre }}" @click="getMaterias(urlRelativeGetMaterias, selectBimestre)">{{ bimestre }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="selectMateria" class="form-label fw-bold">Materia:</label>
                        <!-- Select para mostrar las materias obtenidas -->
                        <select id="selectMateria" x-model="selectMateria" class="form-select">
                            <option selected>{{ selected }}</option>
                            <template x-for="showMaterias in listMaterias">
                                <!-- Option para realizar la solicitud GET para obtener las Unidades -->
                                <option x-text="`${showMaterias.materia}.`" :value="showMaterias.id" @click="getUnidades"></option>
                            </template>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Estos son los modelos de la app de materias

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Materia(models.Model):
    materia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objetivo = models.TextField()
    bimestre = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Materias"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.materia}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.materia


class Unidad(models.Model):
    unidad = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    materia = models.ForeignKey(Materia, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Unidades"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.unidad}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.unidad
```

y este es el modelo donde almaceno los concepto

```
from django.db import models
from materias.models import Materia, Unidad


# Create your models here.
class Concepto(models.Model):
    concepto = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    significado = models.TextField()
    unidad = models.ForeignKey(Unidad, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    materia = models.ForeignKey(Materia, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Conceptos"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.concepto}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.concepto
```